# Change APN settings by code in Android

Tags: android

I want to change the APN settings by code in Android. I need it to be done from browser.

Is it possible to change the APN settings from browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user to that particular screen from your application. I doubt if you can do it directly.  Or you can search for that source code in this application
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone

and see if you can use reflections to achieve this.